# What expression can I use in matlab to remove the negative component of a sine wave so it can look like the picture below?

Tags: design

The image shows a sine wave is obtained using MATLAB. I would like to know what they possibly multiplied or what expression could one use in MATLABto get this wave instead of a complete sine wave.[image]

Comment: Request @Signal to mark an answer as accepted if they are satisfied with their application, to help any future readers

Comment: @Shreyas It's customary to wait _at least_ 24 hours after the question has been asked before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know MatLab but I suspect that (y + |y|)/2 (where |y| is the absolute value of the function) would do the trick.

When the function is positive the two halves add to give a regular sine. When the function is negative the function and absolute value cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

The matlab way, using logical indexing:

```
t = -4*pi:.01:4*pi;
a = sin(t);
a(a <= 0) = 0;
plot(a)
```